# Configuring data binding for app modules that don't directly use data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I've started to read [about data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) and I encounted in the following statement:

> Note: You must configure data binding for app modules that depend on
>   libraries that use data binding, even if the app module doesn't
>   directly use data binding.

What does the following statement mean? Why is it necessary to configure data binding for app modules that don't directly use data binding? 
What is an app module that depend on libraries that use data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So an app module is just a module in your project. By default you only have one app module called `app` (you can see it in the Project view in Android Studio).

If a app module has a dependency that uses databinding, you will need to configure it for that module, regardless if the module itself uses databinding or not. If you don't do that, the library will not work correctly.

On well documented libraries, the authors will probably mention that in the installation instructions.